# Draggable property lost after expanding node with bootstrap-treeview

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, treeview

I am trying to develop a widget for a web application in which the user can drag and drop items from a hierarchical list into a div. For the list I am using the well know [bootstrap-treeview plugin](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-treeview) and for the drag and drop feature JQuery UI draggable and droppable functions.

It works well after page load, the items in the list can be dragged. However, as soon as I expand one of the list items, they can be dragged no longer.

I've tried to re-add the draggable handle using the expandNode event listener, but it does not work. I've also checked that event is being fired, but for some reason the draggable condition is not attached again to the list items.

You can check the minimal code reproducing the error in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xemy50e3/1/).

Any idea about what am I doing wrong?

Below all the code for completeness.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.css">

        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>        

        <style>
            .item-list {
              height: 8em;
              color: black;
            }

            .droppable-area {
              height: 8em;
              outline: 2px dashed blue;
            }
        </style>

    </head>



    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <p>
            Item list:
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6" id="item-list">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 droppable-area">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var enableDraggables = function(event, data) {
          $(".node-item-list").draggable({
            opacity: 0.7,
            helper: "clone",
            revert: true
            }); 
            return true;
        };

        var itemTree = [
            { text: "item 1", nodes:[{text: "subitem 1-1"},{text: "subitem 1-2"}]},
          { text: "item 2", nodes:[{text: "subitem 2-1"},{text: "subitem 2-2"},{text: "subitem 2-3"}]},
          { text: "item 3" }
        ];

        $("#item-list").treeview({
          data: itemTree,
          expandIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right",
          collapseIcon: "glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down",
          onNodeSelected: enableDraggables,
          onNodeUnselected: enableDraggables,
          onNodeChecked: enableDraggables,
          onNodeUnchecked: enableDraggables,
          onNodeCollapsed: enableDraggables,
          onNodeExpanded: enableDraggables
        });
        $("#item-list").treeview('collapseAll', {
          silent: true
        });

        enableDraggables();

        $(".droppable-area").droppable({
          accept: ".node-item-list"
        });


    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bootstrap-treeview` destroys and re-builds the tree every time a node is expanded or collapsed which is removing the classes added by `draggable`.

In order to keep the `ui-draggable` and `ui-draggable-handle` classes on each node after the tree is rendered you will have to edit the `Tree.prototype.template` item template within the `bootstrap-treeview` plugin to include those classes:

```
Tree.prototype.template = {
    ...
    item: '<li class="list-group-item ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle"></li>',
    ...
};
```

**Update:**

Based on your comment, you should be able to modify the `Tree.prototype.buildTree` function to only apply the `ui-draggable` classes to the item by checking the `nodes` or `level` properties. You'll have to define what the constraints are.

```
var treeItem = $(_this.template.item)
                .addClass('node-' + _this.elementId)
                .addClass(level === 1 ? 'ui-draggable' : '') // modify this line as needed
                ...
```

Comment: Interesting solution, it seems to solve the problem. However it has two drawbacks. First, I have to modify the library, and second, that makes all nodes draggable, and I only need leaf nodes to be draggable. The first drawback is something I could live with, but the second is something I need to solve.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Finally I used a slightly modified form of your solution, but basically it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am also having trouble to solve your problem. My guess is that both plugins are just not compatible. You could try using another plugin such as https://github.com/mar10/fancytree which combines both drag and drag and a treeview.